# Language switcher block hides for authenticated user

Tags: i18n-l10n, debugging

I have a language switcher added to my site. It works fine as long as I'm an unauthenticated user. Logging into site replaces it with:

```
<span data-big-pipe-placeholder-id="callback=Drupal%5Cblock%5CBlockViewBuilder%3A%3AlazyBuilder&amp;args%5B0%5D=languageswitcher&amp;args%5B1%5D=full&amp;args%5B2%5D&amp;token=nsR3jJa8bJz_M5rp3ogwQZ8Ownrs-S1wckm2wsrv1BY"></span>
```

I see this behavior also  when I add a `message block` to any of the regions.

I'm also using big pipe. Could it be causing some issue? Is this a bug with language switcher block?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please don't post links to your projects. It always appears like spam and/or click-bait. Furthermore the questions (and potential answers) on Drupal Answers remain, while your project moves to another domain and so on... - Always describe your problem as good as you can in a textual representation; consider pasting HTML source, error log excerpts, or similar with your question. - Rule of thumb: If you need to paste in a link to your site to make us understand the issue, your question is too broad and needs further information.

Answer (score 0):

Things you can try one of the following:

- Uninstall Big Pipe module
- Try switching to another theme. It might be that the active theme has a JS error which breaks the execution of the Big Pipe
- Enable JS aggregation if disabled, or disable it if enabled
- Check for console erros in the developer tools